# BigCommerce Stencil Checkout - Edit Available Shipping and Billing Countries/States

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a safe way to alter the Shipping and Billing Country and State select dropdowns in checkout? It would be nice if this were a setting a seller could control in the admin panel, but I don't believe it is available.

Here is an example of how I have handled this in the past, but **I would like to avoid writing JavaScript to manipulate the DOM and override the default functionality on page load** as I'm aware this is not best practice and likely not supported by all browsers...

EDIT: I saw this PR come in yesterday, but I don't think we can edit the actual `{{{ checkout.checkout_content }}}`.
https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil/pull/940

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/checkout.php"){
    console.log("loaded from analytics box");

    function handleUSOnlyBillingCountry(){
        $('#FormField_11 option[value="United States"]').addClass("keep-me");
        $('#FormField_11 option[value="Canada"]').addClass("keep-me");
        $('#FormField_11 option[value="Puerto Rico"]').addClass("keep-me");
        $('#FormField_11 option:first-child').addClass("keep-me");
        $('#FormField_11 option').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass("keep-me")){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I checked the shipping configuration on the store, and confirmed only United States is available for shipping, but all countries still show in checkout. Once an address outside of the configured shipping zone is entered, it says "One of more of the items in your cart cannot be shipped to your location". This helps, but I would like to remove the options completely.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've definitely had this request in the past, but there isn't a current stencil alternative from javascript. If you use Optimized Checkout, the country dropdown is automatically limited to the countries you ship to.

In developer or blueprint checkout, the only currently viable solution (to my knowledge) is javascript. I don't believe we'll be adding this to legacy checkouts, but we are working on a future Checkout SDK which could be consumed and have (hopefully) fewer potential points of failure for this change.

Comment: Ok, cool. Do you when the Optimized Checkout testing will be done and customers will see it 100% of the time?

Comment: @tim-diztinct that should currently be the case. If you have optimized checkout turned on under advanced settings > checkout, it will be on 100% for all customers.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I haven't tested this in the past week, but I wanted to let you know the documentation still says only some customers will see it. "Please note that even with the new checkout turned on, only a percentage of your customers will see the new checkout while others will see our Legacy checkout." https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Optimized-Single-Page-Checkout

Comment: @tim-diztinct Yeah, I made a poor assumption since I thought we'd have ramped up by now given how long it has been out. I believe it is an experiment we can ramp, but I don't know how long we will leave the current 50/50 default. If you'd like 100%, I'm sure I could force that on a store.

Answer (score -1):

I was under the impression that the list of shipping countries had to be configured thru the control panel thru the use of shipping zones. https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Setting-Up-Shipping-Zones

Comment: I just edited my post. I don't believe this is the case. I double checked the admin of the store and only a United States shipping rule is configured, but all countries are showing in the checkout shipping step.

Comment: It isn't the case. The only change that will occur is the presence of an error message, not a change in the displayed list.